# How to configure templates for task creation using @CurrentIteration in Azure DevOps

Tags: templates, azure-devops, azure-boards

I have created a template to generate task under the user story in Azure DevOps board. However, while using this template, encountering error for Iteration path where I have used @CurrentIteration.

Template location: [Project Settings >> Team Configuration >> Templates >> Task]

Error message:

> ADD A NEW LINKED WORK ITEM : Could not create work item. Error: TF401347: Invalid tree name given for work item -1, field 'System.IterationPath'.. Please check the template used in this action

[image]

How to fix this issue with @CurrentIteration in Iteration path?

Answer (score 1):

In the work item templates, you need to use the exact values to set the **Iteration Path**. It is not supported to use the **`@CurrentIteration`** macro to set the **Iteration Path** in the work item templates.

The value of **`@CurrentIteration`** is dynamical and will always point to the **Iteration Path** that contains current date. The **`@CurrentIteration`** macro generally can be used in work item queries.

When creating a new work item:

- If the new item is created under an existing parent item, this new item will inherit the same **Iteration Path** from the parent item by default.
- If the new item is not created under an existing parent item, it will use the value of **`@CurrentIteration`** by default.

Comment: As clarified in my above answer, It is not supported to use the **`@CurrentIteration`** macro to set the Iteration Path in the work item templates. you need to provide the exact values. I'd like to know if you have further questions for this case. @cjmax006

Answer (score 0):

You should not customize `@CurrentIteration` value. This Value is dynamically calculated from the Team Settings. You have to add your template to the corresponding team with the default `@CurrentIteration`. You may switch a team here:

[image]